# Why do my lists of floats get collapsed?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I defined two types of new floats, but when I try to list each of them separately, they get collapsed into the same list. Here is an `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=loa,
    listname=List of A,
    name=FloatA,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=chapter,
]{floata}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=loa,
    listname=List of B,
    name=FloatB,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=chapter,
]{floatb}

\begin{document}

\listoffloatas
\listoffloatbs

\newpage

\begin{floata}
\caption[float a]{float a example}
\end{floata}

\begin{floatb}
\caption[float b]{float b example}
\end{floatb}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are using the same file extension for both (loa).

Answer (score 5):

The file extensions of both list definitions are the same, this means both float types will be put to the `A` list (`loa`). Change the second list extension to, say `lob`, for example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=loa,
    listname=List of A,
    name=FloatA,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=chapter,
]{floata}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=lob,
    listname=List of B,
    name=FloatB,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=chapter,
]{floatb}

\begin{document}

\listoffloatas
\listoffloatbs

\newpage

\begin{floata}
\caption[float a]{float a example}
\end{floata}

\begin{floatb}
\caption[float b]{float b example}
\end{floatb}

\end{document}
```